# Wpf UserControl hosted in Winforms MDI application. Launch Dialogbox

Tags: wpf, user-controls, position, dialog

I have written wpf Usercontrol which will be hosted in Winforms MDI window. UseControl has a code to launch Wpf Modal dialog box but the positions of the Dialog box is random. I am not sure how to hook the owner property for dialog so that i can center the dialog window to the parent MDI child window.

Ex.

```
Window w = new Window() //wpf Window
w.Owner = //Don't know how to put Winforms Window here
w.ShowDiaog();
```

Any ideas please

Thanks